# Looping trouble in Ruby for small script

Tags: ruby

I am working on a Ruby exercise but I'm not getting my desired output.

The problem starts around step 2 in my algorithm I think..the counter of the while loop confuses me a little and I'm not sure how to end the while loop. But other than that, I think the code is mostly ok.

> Write a program, which will find all such numbers between 1000 and 3000 (both included) such that each digit of the number is an even number.
>
> The numbers obtained should be printed in a comma-separated sequence on a single line.

I want to implement:

1. Iterate over the entire range (`1000..3000`) and identify all evens, and store them into a separate array called `array_evens`.
2. Iterate over `array_evens` and divide each even number into separate digits.
3. Iterate over all those digits and determine whether each is even or false with `even?`.
4. If that number is even, push it to an array called `all_evens_baby`

Here is my code:

```
range = (1000..3000)
array_even = Array.new()
even_digits_number = []
n = 0 #counter variable
all_evens_baby = []
even_or_odd = nil


range.select do |x|
  if x.even?
    array_even = array_even.push(x)

    while (n <= array_even.length)
      #The placement of this while loop may be wrong.
      #iterate over all evens to divide all numbers into singular digits

      current_divided_number = array_even[n].to_s.chars
      current_divided_number.map do |x|
        #iterate over all digits to determine if even or odd

        even_or_odd = x.to_i.even? #=> true or false

        if even_or_odd == true
          all_evens_baby = even_digits_number.push(array_even[n])
        else
        end
      end
      n+=1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: which ruby version are you using?

Comment: I am using version  2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First an attempt to get the current code working - it wasn't far off:

```
range = (1000..3000)
array_even = Array.new()
all_evens_baby = []

range.each do |x|
  if x.even?
    array_even.push(x)
  end
end # you'r done here, step 1 is finished.
    # shorter is:  array_even = range.select(&:even?)

array_even.select do |x|
  current_divided_number = x.to_s.chars
  n = 0 #counter variable
  current_divided_number.each do |d|
    n=n+1 if d.to_i.even?
  end
  all_evens_baby << x if n == 4
end

puts all_evens_baby.join(",")
```

The first step is unnecessary, step 2/3 will filter the odds out anyway.
Ruby 2.4 has a nice method to obtain the digits of an integer, called `digits`, so converting to a string can be avoided.

Have a look at:

```
all_evens_baby = (1000..3000).select do |num|
  num.digits.all? do |d|
    d.even?
  end  #if this is true, num will be in all_evens_baby
end
puts all_evens_baby.join(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
range = (1000..3000)
# Return all values from range where the block evaluates to true and put them into a list called result
result = range.select do |number|
  # convert the number to a string and convert every character back to a number (digits) then check if all digits are even
  number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).all? { |n| n.even? }
end
# create a string from the number where elements are spearated by a ','
puts result.join(',')
```

Explanation:

```
result = range.select 
returns the value
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution in one line

```
all_evens_baby=(1000..3000).select {|a| a.even?}.map {|i| i.to_s.chars}.flatten.map {|i| i.to_i}.select {|i| i.even?}
```